# Deleting some chat messages

Tags: support, chat

I want to remove a few chat messages which may cause some problem to me later. If a mod contacts me, then I would inform them the chat messages.

This is not my main account. Mods can verify it. When the messages are deleted, the mods may delete this account.

Comment: @Glorfindel Room owners can't delete messages. They can only move them.

Comment: It is probably better if you use the ["Contact Us" link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact). This kind of requests aren't exactly on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove a few chat messages which may cause some problem to me later. If a mod contacts me, then I would inform them the chat messages.

Even better, contact an employee! Use the ["Contact Us" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) in order to explain your problem to someone at SE and maybe they can help you. In my experiences with them, they were quite quick and helpful with tricky situations. And also, why would chat messages cause problems for you? If you did something against the rules, you unfortunately would have to face the consequences. If you didn't, chat messages should never stir up trouble... most of the time.

Of course, as @rene said, you can flag one of your chat messages as well. Your description of why the messages need to be removed has to be under 150 chars though.

> When the messages are deleted, the mods may delete this account.

You can also send a second request using the ["Contact Us" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) for moderators to remove your account. Just fill in the correct information and your account should be deleted in no time.

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply flag the message for mod attention? You only have 150 chars to explain what is wrong. I don't recall chat mod flags are a privilege that come with reputation.

Comment: @rene I kinda forgot about that. I'll fix it